# Referencing a string inside a Formula Array in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

Need some help referencing a string in an Index formula array

My code below:

```
Sub Loop_Test2()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim CountAll As Long
Dim CountXL As Long
Dim CustomerName As String

ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate

CountAll = ActiveSheet.Range("A35")

For j = 1 To CountAll
i = 2

CountXL = Cells(i, j).Value

For i = 1 To CountXL
CustomerName = Cells(1, j).Value
'MsgBox CustomerName
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=CustomerName,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1))*1,2),0)"
Next i

Next j

End Sub
```

There is no error; however i need This part fixed so it references the value instead of the actual word inside the formula:

IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=CustomerName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, use below:

```
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""" & CustomerName & """,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1))*1,2),0)"
```

in general, if you need concat string use `"formula_par21""" & value & """formula_part2`, if it's number - without double quotes, like  `"formula_par21" & value & "formula_part2`

**"" in VBA = " in string variable**

Comment: thank you very much this is working. I have another error now though. The part for ROW(1:1) should increase every time ROW(2,2) and so on. any idea how to fix this? I

Comment: I tried using this: For j = 1 To CountAll
i = 2

CountXL = Cells(i, j).Value
    R = 1
    For i = 1 To CountXL
    CustomerName = Cells(1, j).Value
    'MsgBox CustomerName
    MsgBox R
    Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""" & CustomerName & """,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(" & R & " : " & R & "))*1,2),0)"
    R = R + 1
    Next i
Next j

Comment: Thanks for the response; however i am getting a runtime error - object defined error 1004. Any idea?

Comment: Where are you getting error? Which line? Post your full code in question, please.

Answer (score 1):

```
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""""" & CustomerName & """"",ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1))*1,2),0)"
```

You gotta double the "" in the Formulas in VBA --> "" = """"

Here is a simple example why you might get the errors:

Excel Formula:

```
=If(A1<>"";A1;B1)
```

VBA Formula

```
"=IF(A1<>"""",A1,B1)"
```

so i would recommend you to try this:

```
Cells(i + 2, j).FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$A:$A=""""" & CustomerName & """"",ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)),ROW(1:1))*1,2),0)"
```